# Modify a global variable from a function

Tags: jquery

I am new to jQuery and I need some help here.
I got 3 variables, a, b and c. C is the sum of a an b.

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
var a = 0;
var b = 0;
var c = (a+b);
console.log(c);
$('#x').click(function(){
  if ( $('#x').hasClass('selected') && a < 2 && c < 4) { 
    a++;
  } 
  console.log(a);
});

$('#y').click(function(){
  if ( $('#y').hasClass('selected') && b < 2 && c < 4) { 
    b++;
  } 
  console.log(b);
});
  $('#total').html(c);
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="x" class="selected"> A </button>
<button id="y" class="selected"> B </button>
<p id ="total">0</p>
```

I don't know how can the code update the C variable after A and B had been changed by the click function (if i predefine A for example with the value of 3 I get the corect value of C).

Comment: Please give better variable and button names

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is not recalculating your variable, so you need to do something like that:

```js
    $( document ).ready(function() {
      var a = 0;
      var b = 0;
      var c = 0;
      console.log('C = '+c);
      $('#x').click(function(){
        if ( $('#x').hasClass('selected') && a < 2 && c < 4) { 
          a++;
        } 
        console.log('A = '+a);
        show();
      });

      $('#y').click(function(){
        if ( $('#y').hasClass('selected') && b < 2 && c < 4) { 
          b++;
        } 
        console.log('B = '+b);
        show();
      });
    
      function show() {
        c = a + b;
        console.log('C = '+c);
        $('#total').html(c);    
      }
        
    });
```

```html
   

 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <button id="x" class="selected"> A </button>
    <button id="y" class="selected"> B </button>
    <p id ="total">0</p>
```

You need to call a function to recalculate you C and show that.

Comment: Thank's for the help Matheus! I got the flow logic now.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that `c` is not being changed when the buttons are clicked. You can simply add `a` and `b` and set the html of the `p` tag in each of the click handlers. Or assign `a + b` to `c` in each of the handlers and then set the value of `c` to the `p` tag.

In the following example, I've used the former approach.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var a = 0;
  var b = 0;
  var c = (a + b);

  $('#x').click(function() {
    if ($('#x').hasClass('selected') && a < 2 && c < 4) {
      a++;
    }

    $('#total').html(a + b);
  });

  $('#y').click(function() {
    if ($('#y').hasClass('selected') && b < 2 && c < 4) {
      b++;
    }

    $('#total').html(a + b);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="x" class="selected"> A </button>
<button id="y" class="selected"> B </button>
<p id="total">0</p>
```